# Move file with prompt using bash script

Tags: bash

When I do a rm, it will call alias

```
rm='mv -t /root/Desktop/tmp'
```

Is it possible to prompt user with move confirmation?

Answer (score 0):

Add -i option:

```
rm='mv -i -t /root/Desktop/tmp'
```

Comment: @daokia Are you sure the alias is working. Can you try `mv -i` manually? If not you could use a function that would prompt you instead.

Comment: @daokia Make sure you declare you alias as `alias rm='mv -i -t /root/Desktop/tmp'`

Answer (score 0):

I tested this a little. The mv only prompts with the -i switch if it is going to overwrite a file of the same name. If not, it just does the move anyway. Without the -i switch, it does the move without prompting, whether the file is there or not. Typical UNIX economy: the move doesn't hurt anything if it does it without overwriting another file, even when interactive is turned on.

Answer (score 0):

Use a function instead and code as you wish, e.g.

```
rm()
{
    local file="$1"
    local choice
    read -p "do you really want to remove '${file}'? [Y/n] " choice
    [[ -z "${choice}" || "${choice}" == Y ]] && mv -t /root/Desktop/tmp "${file}"
}
```